# login to remote Win10 and retrieve file

Tags: scripting, windows-10, remote, copy

Currently doing a manual daily backup of certain files, tars and zips, from a number of Win10 boxes to a master Win10 box.  Backups are done by RDP - copy - paste.  There has to be a way to script this.  Please avoid: network file share, folder mapping, installing ssh or other server, or any permanent connection.  The idea is to script what has been happening manually: open a connection with the known login, grab the files, and close the connection.  Is there a way for a batch or powershell script on the master to fetch these files using the known user/pass on the remote boxes?

Comment: Not really network file sharing necessarily or folder mapping, but could you just simply copy from the `C$` administrative share to the master `C$` administrative share?  By network file share I'm assuming you don't want to share the folder with the backups, which the administrative share is already shared by default usually.

Comment: Using C$ requires enabling file and print sharing.  This is not enabled.

Comment: Administrative share are enabled by default (aka c$, or IPC$, etc..) Please state why you block that as it prevent to manage those computers in the end.

Comment: yes, this should be possible using powershell scripts: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.2